# Complex integration misconception?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Playing around with the complex integretion I encountered the following:

Consider a holomorphic function $f(z)$ on $\Omega$. Let's say this holomorphic function has a primitve $F(z)$ such that $F'(z) = f(z)$ on $\Omega$.

Then for each closed $\Gamma\subseteq \Omega$, since $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$

$$\begin{align}
 \int_\Gamma f(z)\text{d} z &= 0\\
 \int_\Gamma F'(z) \text{d} z & = 0\\
 F(z) &\color{red}{\stackrel{?}{=}} C
\end{align}$$

Where $C$ denotes a complex number.

#### Really?

I don't think this is right, is it? But what's wrong with the argument?

Comment: Is $\Gamma$ closed?

Comment: How are you getting from your second line to your third line? In particular, I can take any analytic function (like, say, $z^s$) and integrate it (or its derivatives) around a closed loop and get $0$. This doesn't tell me much about the integrand (or its antiderivative)

Comment: @mixedmath I had a feeling that would be the problem, still mixing real and complex integration. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that an indefinite integral is a function of a variable (with arbitrary constant), but the integral along the path $\Gamma$ is analogous to a definite integral--it's just a number. The variable has been "integrated out".